# Chart onclick load another chart - EventHandler not firing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have created a visual web part in VS 2010 share point 2007.
I have

1. Start date
2. End date
3. Search button

On click of chart I had created a pie chart and column chart .

Now of pie or column chart another chart should load based on region selected

```
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    this.chrtRigPie.Click += new ImageMapEventHandler(this.chrtRigPie_click);


                }

       }

        private void chrtRigPie_click(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageMapEventArgs e)
    {
        //int sliceindex = int.Parse(e.PostBackValue);

        //Int32 ipos = e.PostBackValue.LastIndexOf(",");
        //String sSeries = e.PostBackValue.Substring(0, ipos);
        //String sStartDate = e.PostBackValue.Substring((ipos + 1), (e.PostBackValue.Length - (ipos + 1)));
        //string strDevice = e.PostBackValue;
        if (e.PostBackValue.Contains("#VALX"))
        {


            string[] postValues = e.PostBackValue.Split(',');
            string COMPANY = postValues[1];
            Session["Company"] = COMPANY;
        }
```

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

After the postback
`this.chrtRigPie.Click += new ImageMapEventHandler(this.chrtRigPie_click);` 
will be invalid. So the handler does not fire.